# How to find a closest street

Tags: google-maps

I'm reading through Google Maps API documentation and I wonder if such a think is possible:

1. I specify the point (by coords)
2. I search for all roads, and junctions around the node (say in 1km radius)
3. I get parameters for the streets around (polyline coords)

Is it reachable, or google do not share that data?

Thanks in advance
Rafal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can image writing up a little script that generates a bunch of random points within a 1km radius and then performs directions services via Google Maps API to obtain all possible routes and thus streets within a 1km radius.  However, this is problematic since it is kinda against the Google Maps TOS of displaying this information only on a map within a website and not extracting data for you personal use as this would be.

A better approach would be looking into utilizing [Open Street Map](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) data where you can download street data from a specific viewport.  If buying street network data is an option, you can go to a commercial outlet such as NAVTEQ or PTV which post-processes NAVTEQ data to a format for use in the transport modeling software package you mention on your blog.

Comment: thanks fo answer. Mine conclusion was more or less similar. Probably there is some way to collect this data from google (not straightforward) but it harms google ToS and "we do not want cesar to be angry" :)  I'm plaing now with OpenStreetMap and API gives great opportunities, however data feed is not reliable - there are some white gaps.